# Android sqlite update row by calling method

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update a row in my sqlite database but i cant find out what is wrong... I'm using this method id my DbAdapter :

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String TimeDone, String ActDone) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;


    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TIME, TimeDone);
    newValues.put(KEY_ACT, ActDone);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

And in my Activity i try to update a row by doing this :

```
                    String a = "20:34:23";
                    String item2 = spnr.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    long rowId = spnr.getSelectedItemId();
                    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
                    newValues.put("Time", a);
                    newValues.put("Activity",item2);

                    myDb.updateRow(rowId, a, item2);
```

Am i forgetting something , or i'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I have tried this way;

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String TimeDone, String ActDone) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "= ?" + rowId;


    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TIME, TimeDone);
    newValues.put(KEY_ACT, ActDone);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

But i get the following error :

```
12-20 17:45:12.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: variable number must be between ?1 and ?999 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE MainTable SET Activity=?,Time=? WHERE _id= ?0
```

And if i do this way :

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String TimeDone, String ActDone)  {


        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_TIME, TimeDone);
        newValues.put(KEY_ACT, ActDone);


        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,newValues, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) })!= 0;
    }
```

I get no errors but the row dosent update .

Comment: try using String where = KEY_ROWID + "?=" + rowId;

Comment: It have just used something like it...please wait I'm putting code..hope it may help you

Comment: somehow i deleted my comment, sorry ! Okay thank you :)

Comment: No, still the same... I dont get an error now but it still dosent update the row :\

Comment: Did you try below answer? and why did you use boolean function?

Comment: I have updated the answer...it will surely work..(As it seems to work in my project)

Comment: I did, and i made it boolean so if the field exists it gets updated but what do you suggest, maybe the problem is there since i get no errors...

Comment: I'm going to edit my question so you can see better what i'm trying

Comment: ok...notify me when updated

Comment: Replace last line with return db.update((DATABASE_TABLE,newValues, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) })!= 0);

Comment: I did it but still no errors and no update. I think the method is well done, maybe the problem is in my activity, i'll try to do some changes but it looks all fine to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not giving you the correct ID:

```
long rowId = spnr.getSelectedItemId();
```

Instead, call getSelectedItem() and get your ID from the object.

Comment: If i do that i need to put it like this : long rowId = (long) spnr.getSelectedItem(); 
But i get error in java :

12-20 18:12:01.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: The point is that `getSelectedItemId` does not work unless you wrote your own custom adapter override `getItemId`. Did you do that? Otherwise you need to store the IDs somewhere you get at them. The adapter does not know what your IDs are.

Comment: You are right! If i insert the id manually it works... But how do i make it like you said ? because, if i put it as long it needs the cast and i get the error, and if i try to pass it as String it simple dosent work

Comment: Honestly I cant really give you a quick answer how to create a custom spinner adapter. Maybe start with some articles like this one http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Comment: Thank you, i managed a solution by getting the Name of the product instead of the ID... Fast solution for that problem :)

Comment: Yes that will work if you don't have two products with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to put `?` in `String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;`

Then change it to `String where = KEY_ROWID + "= ?" + rowId;`

or try something like this:

```
public int updateRow(long rowId, String TimeDone, String ActDone)  {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TIME, TimeDone);
    newValues.put(KEY_ACT, ActDone);


        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,newValues, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(rowID) });
    }
```

Hope it may help.